# node-v59-linux-x64/grpc_node.node is missing

Tags: node.js, firebase, github, npm, grpc

I am trying to use Firebase admin SDK in my server. When I deploy I get the error I am missing file node-v59-linux-x64/grpc_node.node in firebase-admin node_module map. I added "grpc": "1.7.1" in my package, but I still do not get that file after NPM update. I get an older version, node-v57. I also checked this path https://registry.npmjs.org/grpc/-/grpc-1.7.1.tgz, but I could not locate the file. I deleted my node_modules map and ran npm install again, still no node-v59.

How/where can I download that file? Is there any one who can put the file here so I can manually add it?

> Error: Cannot find module
>   '/data/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v59-linux-x64/grpc_node.node'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. You can download the file here: https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.7.1/node-v59-linux-x64.tar.gz

Comment: Where do I copy this file to?

Answer (score 7):

This kind of problem is usually caused by installing the library on one system, then deploying and running it on a different system that requires a different binary file.

The simplest solution to this problem is to run `npm rebuild` after deployment on the system you deployed on.

Alternatively, if `npm rebuild` is not an option, you can pre-install the binary for the system you are deploying on by running `npm install` with some extra options. The `--target` argument allows you to install for a different version of Node. An argument of `--target=9.0.0` installs the binary for Node 9 (only the major version has to match). The `--target_platform` argument allows you to install for a specific operating system: `windows`, `linux`, or `darwin` (Mac). The `--target_arch` argument lets you install for a different processor architecture: `ia32`, `x64`, or `arm`. And finally, the `--target_libc` argument lets you select binaries built for a different libc: `glibc` or `musl` (for Alpine Linux).

So, in your case, you should be able to get that binary by running

```
npm install --target=9.0.0 --target_platform=linux --target_arch=x64
```

Comment: I was having the similar error message `Error: Cannot find module 'project/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v59-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'` I have not moved the code but I think I recently upgraded node by a major reversion (8 => 9). `npm rebuild` did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This helped in my case, based on @murgatroid99’s answer:

```
npm rebuild --target=8.1.0 --target_platform=linux --target_arch=x64 --target_libc=glibc --update-binary
```

It downloads the required binary to your `node_modules/grpc` directory.

I run macOS X on my dev machine and I’m deploying to AWS Lambda; this keeps both runtime versions installed, which means I can develop and test locally and then deploy to Lambda.